# Serenity aggregate not generating results in correct folder

Tags: serenity-bdd

When running the following gradle command

`.\gradlew.bat clean test aggregate -Dserenity.outputDirectory=reports/report_20160612_103558`

results are not getting generated into "report_20160612_103558", instead half are getting stored in "reports" folder and other half getting stored in  "report_20160612_103558". [Adding screen shot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmOrD.png).

[Index.html is blank and says no tests executed, where tests executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgEhS.jpg).

In `serenity.properties` I have `serenity.outputDirectory=reports`, which should be overwritten when running the above gralde command. Please suggest if I have to do any changes and let me know for more details.

Removed serenity.outputDirectory=reports from serenity.properties  and ran the commands still no change in behavior.

Comment: Try removing `serenity.outputDirectory=reports` from `serenity.properties` and change call `clean test aggregate` to `clean test serenity:aggregate`. Also, consider removing `clean` goal from your call statement. Does it not erase all your reports?

Comment: thank you for response. yeah clean goal is erasing all the results. When I don't use clean command  and run as follows. set mytimestamp=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
.\gradlew.bat test aggregate -Dserenity.outputDirectory=reports/report_%mytimestamp%.. it does not run test task, it is just running only aggregate task. so for debug purpose I had added clean which I have to remove.

Comment: executed "clean test serenity:aggregate" getting error as Project 'serenity' not found in root project 'Automation-SerenityBDD'.

Comment: If you run only `clean test serenity:aggregate` you need to also specify `serenity.outputDirectory` in your statement. If you don't, it will look for a Serenity report in a default location, which would be your project folder.

Comment: @JDelorean  Ran this goal , set mytimestamp=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
.\gradlew.bat test -Dserenity.outputDirectory=reports/report_%mytimestamp% aggregate  Its creating folder with timestamp under reports directory. but not executing any tests.  I don't know what to do to make it work.

Comment: This workd thanks so much @J